# Exclude Some Files From a Maven Build

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We use maven as our build tool.We have 6 different modules that are built one after another by parent pom.The pom.xml prepares a bundle.
What we would like to do is, exclude some files(which can be any file) while building the bundle. In other words,those files should not be present in the jar that is created. Like, if a java file is excluded, its corresponding .class file should not be there in the jar created.
 Also, the files that have to be excluded may change(WRT the name, not the content).
We use Jenkins as our CI tool, so if any plugins are available for achieving the above functionality. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [maven jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html). There is a way to exclude artifacts from the packaged jar.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Eldad,thanx for your reply.We are actually using maven-bundle-plugin which also creates jar/OSGi bundles.Sorry, my bad...I didn't mention it in my question in the first place.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it. I guess you need to dig into its documentation.